# How to handle an API call on rotation changes?

Tags: android, api, viewmodel, screen-rotation

Please help with these problems:

1. In my app I have both portrait and landscape screens. I know how to handle data using view model or saved instance state. I have 7 api calls on one activity but when I rotate screen api call stops in between so is there any trick to rotate screen after last api call success so I have all data stored in view model or something helpful.
2. Example- if its login screen user enters id password and clicks login button on screen rotation api call stops and user halts on same screen.

Comment: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/

Answer (score 0):

Try [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), It's a new way of scheduling tasks and [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is intended for tasks that require a guarantee that the system will run them even if the app exits and as you  know how to work with new Architecture Components like ViewModel, I am sure [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) will solve your problem.